# Abusing JavaScript string operations

Tags: javascript

I've got this function in javascript:

```
g.changeImage = function (a) {
    h.src = "image" + a + ".png";
};
```

It's used like this:

```
g.changeImage(2);
```

And it changes image h. The problem is, that it cannot use image from other directory than current.

I'm writing "addon" for the website which should hook into the existing script and change few things. One of them require changing `h.src`. Is there any way I can fool the browser and change the address of h to custom url using only the function given?

I can't access `h` directly, nor change existing script on the website. I can only use function given.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In short, not easily, and not cleanly.  If you could create a subdirectory named `images` then perhaps the value of `a` could be `s\someothername`, yielding `images\someothername.png`.

Comment: *Why* are you restricted to only using that function?

Comment: @g.d.d.c I have no access to the host server.

Comment: @Pointy becouse h is created inside self-called function, it looks like this:
`function(a,b,c){ /*code, code, code*/ var h; }(document,window,jQuery)`

Comment: Any workaround to access inner varriables of something like that function would be great...

Answer (score 1):

One option that I can come up with off the top of my head would be to overwrite the function:

Old Function:

```
g.changeImage = function (a) {
    h.src = "image" + a + ".png";
    alert(h.src);
};
g.changeImage("test.png")
```

New Function:

```
g.changeImage = function (a) {
    h.src = "test - new url " + a + ".png";
    alert(h.src);
}
g.changeImage("test")
```

Here's a quick example for you to play with and see if this will work for what you need:  http://jsfiddle.net/2BsQP/

Comment: Overriding the function from console or any other script changes the function context, so Im not able to access the h from there. Still good shoot.

Comment: Gotcha... I'll keep thinking on it.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any way to get scope/context of method... So if it was defined in anonymous function, then I'd get access to all it's contents, including `h`.

Comment: What is h in this context?  I'm thinking maybe access it through the prototype if that's possible...

Comment: The whole structure looks like this: http://pastebin.com/YDLGyCRm Any way to access h would be great...

Comment: Ok, so h is a local variable within the anonymous function - it can't be accessed.  However, it looks like you can create your own variable as a new Image().  You'll basically be rebuilding this anonymous function but will be able access/overwrite h.src since .src is a property of Image().  Does this make sense, or should I give an example?

Comment: Yup, that makes sense... But I'd have to rewrite all functions using h. And thats what I want to avoid :D

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know that there is any other way around this one without being able to change the original function.  The ideal scenario would be to make h public in the original function, then you can do whatever you want to it.